# Where is the best position for a FORM on a landing page?

Tags: forms, conversion, landing-page, multi-step

i am working on a long landing page (at the moment the design is about 9000px long) for the hotel/travel industry.

I was wondering what was the best place to put the request form, right now i am considering **2 possibilities**:

1. Put on the same page the form with the arrival/departure date and number of guests fields only. On the bottom of the form a submit button with text "Reserve" or "Continue" will redirect the user to the full form (on a separate page). This form will have the same pre-compiled fields on the top, and after those there will be some additional ones: like the room and the guest details. On the bottom of the form there will be a summary of what the guest is booking and a "Book now" button.
2. Simply put the full form directly on the bottom of the landing page, so the user will process it without leaving that same page.

**My goals are:**
Usability and conversion.

**My worries:**

- By putting the form on a separate page the user will be less distracted by other elements so will convert better?
- By putting the form on a separate page the user will be worried about seeing only the fields for the arrival/departure date on the main landing page?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated, thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

> "One good test is worth a thousand expert opinons" 
>   - Wernher von Braun

Quite literally. If this question had 1000 answers, and 900 of them said "Go with option A", that still wouldn't guarantee it was the right solution for you.

Of course, experience, expertise, and intuition  are important tools - we can confidently say without testing that a form with 15 fields will be completed less frequently than one with three - but arguably the only way to tell which of two reasonable strategies is best, is to test them on your actual users.

Run an experiment in the form of an A/B test. Location 1 vs Location 2. The result will be the "best position" for the form on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Since the domain is hotel reservations/booking, you will have to add more attractive elements to the page and they shouldn't take the user move away(of course).

You can maintain a column where the form stays always or a fixed top band with a "Book Now" or "Reserve Now" option which can show the form.

Now showing the form shouldn't distract the user. A few possibilities are 
--> A popup
--> A sliding element from the right corner of the window and occupies a few pixels of the right end of the screen.

There could be many more animations possible to make the view better.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes there will always be a sticky menu on the top with a "Reserve" button. I was thinking of simply leaving the form on the bottom of the page and once the button is clicked the page will scroll to the end of the page where the form is located.

Do you think it will be a better option to make the form popup as an overlay instead of scrolling to it?

Comment: Not at all. Scrolling to the bottom has its own advantages. It can be used to show a few good displays and features while scrolling down. Just a feel of marketing. Also make your form simple and short which might attract more users (in other words, we shouldn't take much of the users' time) which you would already be aware of. So wishes for it.